# Scala: return a parametrized instance

Tags: scala, generics, inheritance, traits

I cannot make work the following code:

```
object Factory {
  def apply[U <: Cda](type: MyType.Value): MyUtilTrait[U] = {
    type match {
      case MyType.Value.one => MyOneUtilCustom
      case MyType.Value.two => MyTwoUtilCustom
    }
  }
}
```

=> Expression of type Factory.MyType doesn't conform to expected type MyUtilTrait[U]

```
trait MyUtilTrait[T <: Cda] {}

object MyOneUtilCustom extends MyUtilTrait[CdaOneCustom] { }
object MyTwoUtilCustom extends MyUtilTrait[CdaTwoCustom] { }

case class CdaOneCustom(...) extends Cda {}
case class CdaTwoCustom(...) extends Cda {}

abstract class Cda(...) {}

object MyType extends Enumeration {
  val one, two = Value
 }
```

With the apply, I am supposed to return a MyUtilTrait parametrized with a subtype of Cda, so what's wrong?

Comment: What is `Type`? What is `Type.Value.one` etc? And you cannot use `type` as argument name anyway, because it's a reserved keyword.

Comment: I edited my answer with more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's almost completely impossible to implement this `apply` method with such a signature **[1]**, because someone could come along, define

```
class Unobtanium extends Cda {
  // implement all `Cda` methods by `???`
}
```

and then invoke

```
Factory.apply[Unobtanium](MyType.one)
```

How is a factory supposed to create a `MyUtilTrait[Unobtanium]`, if it knows nothing about `Unobtanium`, and it is the first time it sees this strange type?

Use existential type instead:

```
abstract class Cda {}
case class CdaOneCustom() extends Cda {}
case class CdaTwoCustom() extends Cda {}

trait MyUtilTrait[T <: Cda] {}
object MyOneUtilCustom extends MyUtilTrait[CdaOneCustom] { }
object MyTwoUtilCustom extends MyUtilTrait[CdaTwoCustom] { }

object MyType extends Enumeration {
  val one, two = Value
}

object Factory {
  def apply(typ: MyType.Value): MyUtilTrait[_] = {
    import MyType._
    typ match {
      case `one` => MyOneUtilCustom
      case `two` => MyTwoUtilCustom
    }
  }
}
```

**[1]** Unless your `MyUtilTrait[X]` is something trivial, like `Nil` (which is a `List[X]` for any `X`), or `Consumer[Any]` of some sort, which does not actually care about the type parameter.

Comment: @JoelBerkeley in the cases where existential types can be expressed by simple wildcards, nothing at all changes. In the more complex cases, where you previously wrote `Foo[..., X, ...., X, ...] forSome { type X }`, you would now have to build a little wrapper with type-member around it: `FooWrapper { type X; foo: Foo[..., X, ..., X, ...] }`, so it's not such a dramatic change.

Comment: Thanx for your answers. I am wondering. In java I could do something like MyUtilTrait(? extends Cda) apply(MyType.Value type) = {} is there no equivalent in scala ? Is there nothing like def apply(type: MyType.Value): MyUtilTrait[+Cda] ?

Comment: @Rolintocour `def apply(typ: MyType.Value): MyUtilTrait[_]` is by definition of `MyUtilTrait` the same as `def apply(typ: MyType.Value): MyUtilTrait[_ <: Cda]`, which is essentially the same as the wildcard `public MyUtilTrait<? extends Cda> apply(MyTypeValue typ)` in java, just with question marks instead of underscores. So, I don't understand what you're asking in your follow-up question.

Comment: I had to read answer many times but I got it, from the definition of MyUtilTrait even if I use  MyUtilTrait[_] then _ stands for the T <: Cda

Comment: @Rolintocour Could you maybe point out which part or sentence of the answer is particularly unclear? Was it something about the writing, or was it just a problem with the code? Or was it just the previous comment that was a little bit dense (admittedly, it was...)?

Comment: I blocked on "is by definition of MyUtilTrait the same as" but this was just a problem with the code, to understand that I did the "by definition"